# play and stop spritesheet Using lua for corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, sprite-sheet

I have created a sprite sheet which plays continuously,

```
local sheet3 = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "sample.png",400,317)

local spriteSet3 = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet3, 1, 8)
sprite.add( spriteSet3, "puma", 1, 8, 1000, 0 ) -- play 8 frames every 1000 ms

local instance3 = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet3 )
instance3.x = 2* display.contentWidth / 4 + 30
instance3.y = baseline - 5
instance3.xScale = .5
instance3.yScale = .5

instance3:prepare("puma")
instance3:play()
```

As we know spritesheet shows image sequence in loop. I want to stop play of image sequence after it completes one loop.

Anybody know how can i do this? or at least provide me any link to help me out to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the animation in the first place you set whether or not to loop:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/spriteadd

Alternatively if you need to adjust the animation programmatically (ie. loop until the player does something) then you can set an event listener and call pause() when the loop event happens:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/spriteinstanceaddeventlistener